# Необходимо реализовать регенерацию в игре на python

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Пишу игру на python с помощью pygame, пытался создать регенерацию единицы здоровья раз в 5 секунд, если здоровье неполное.

```
def temp(self):
     while True: # бесконечный цикл
        self.health += 1
        time.sleep(5) # раз в 5 сек

# функция запуска регена хп
def regenerating(self): 
    if self.health < self.max_health:   #если текущее хп меньше максимального
        _thread.start_new_thread(self.temp,()) #новый процес
```

Когда запускаю игру здоровье моментально становится полным, то есть не запускается новый поток. Пожалуйста исправьте ошибку, или предложите свой вариант. Использую thread поскольку игра должна оставаться активной, не ждать пока восполнится жизнь.

Comment: С многопоточность особо не работал, поэтому могу ошибаться. Но, имхо, у вас здесь цикл сразу создаст большое количество потоков, каждый из которых добавит единицу здоровья и уснёт на пять секунд.

Comment: Поток не создаётся, к сожалению, исполняется просто код заложенный в temp.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так надо:

```
def temp(self):
    while self.health < self.max_health:
        self.health += 1
        time.sleep(5) # раз в 5 сек

def regenerating(self): 
    if self.health < self.max_health:
        th = threading.Thread(target=self.temp)
        th.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

вот способ без thread:

```
def regenerating(self): 

 if self.health>self.max_health:
        self.set_health(self.max_health)

 detecting_time=pg.time.get_ticks()
 if self.health < self.max_health and detecting_time%500==0: # в милисекундах 5=500
     self.health += 1
```